# Can I use my SharePoint library like the original Wikipedia?

Tags: search, wiki

I'm not very experienced with SharePoint at all, so this might be a silly question. Here's what I would like to do:

I would like to create my own thematic Wikipedia using a SharePoint library wiki. Is this possible in principle?
If the answer is yes - how do I do it? I'd like to create a main page including a search bar. Inserting a search item should lead to an extra page explaining the item - just like we are all used to it from Wikipedia.

I'd really appreciate any help. thanks in advance!

P.S.: I'd also appreciate a link to a good SharePoint documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial will help you learn how to create wiki pages on a team site. Work with editing tools to format text; change the layout; and insert links, media, and Web Parts.

https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/SharePoint-pages-II-Work-with-wiki-pages-affe755a-7013-4393-8444-93ffa9e2c1e2